# 'getItemSummariesWithoutItemData' creating unexpected results

Tags: yodlee

We're using the REST API in the sandbox environment. I've uploaded my investment accounts into the first test username that was provided using FastLink.

When I run 'getItemSummariesWithoutItemData' in TestDrive I get all the investment accounts as expected. When I repeat the same query using Python I only get back 2 items : Dagbank and DagCreditcard.

Similarly when I retrieve data using 'getItemSummaryForItem1' and a non-DAG itemId in TestDrive, i get data as expected. When I use the same query from python, i get key={}.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen until and unless you are using two different user logins. Please cross check your code.